# Is it possible to have Google Chrome always open shortcuts in a separate window?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome

If Chrome is already open, it opens new sites (e.g. from Windows shortcuts, application shortcuts, or from the Run dialog) in new tabs of the existing instance.

I'd prefer to open new sites in a separate window (a new instance of Chrome).

I don't see that in the options - is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is still possible:

1. Navigate to the webpage.
2. Click menu `⋮` (three dots) → *More Tools* → *Create shortcut…*.
3. Check *Open as window* and press *Create* button.
4. This should open the webpage in a new window (if it doesn't go to step 8).
5. **For taskbar Pinning**: Right click icon showing on taskbar and select *Pin to Taskbar*.
6. **For Start Menu Pinning**: Right click icon showing on the taskbar, and from the popup right click on the icon of the app and select *Pin to Start*.
7. Close window and see if the icon remains where you pinned it.
8. If the icon is not there or the icon reverts to the generic Chrome icon, first make sure the apps is closed and unpinned and

- Navigate to `chrome://apps/`.
- Launch app by clicking on it.
- Repeat steps 5 through 8.

Comment: For those who lose apps unexpectedly (they open a new tab instead of a separate window), visit chrome://apps/ and right-click and select "Install on this device"

Comment: This option seems to have moved from "More Tools" to "Save and Share"

Answer (score 5):

To open in new window add switch --new-window

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  We certainly appreciate your contributions, but can you please cite your source?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the previous answer holds true still, although there are solutions for your problem today.

One solution: Hold down shift when clicking links (also works with shift+enter). https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183101?hl=en. This can be made default using [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

Another solution:
You can use the extension [Tab to Window/Popup](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-to-window-keyboard-sh/adbkphmimfcaeonicpmamfddbbnphikh?hl=en-GB), and create a keyboard shortcut to move the current tab to a new window.

Comment: Yes, I'd say shift + click is the correct answer to the OP

Answer (score 2):

#### Just do the following:

1. Go to the kebab menu <kbd>`⋮`</kbd>
2. Go to More Tools > Create Shortcut
3. Check `Open as window`

   [image: chrome - create shortcut dialog]

---

***If the shortcut immediately merges into your existing chrome window when launched***, and you had previously created a shortcut, *double check the app settings*:

1. Go to `chrome://apps`
2. Right click on the icon
3. Ensure `Open as window` is selected

   [image: chrome apps options]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you click to create a shortcut, there is a checkbox below Open as window'

[image: Picture showing that option]

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Google support thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1eb2eb870ba29e97&hl=en#all).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, it's not possible.

Comment: True, here's the bug report: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1091633

Answer (score 0):

I Know two ways...

1. go to the upper right tu the three dots.
2. go to more tools-create shortcut.
   3.check open as new window.

or

go to chrome://apps
right click the icon
check open as new window

both the same in a way it depends what you use