# Chrome App mode Starts in different Field in Taskbar

Tags: google-chrome, taskbar

I use the Chrome App-Mode in my taskbar, for Youtube for example, by using `--app=https://www.youtube.com`, and put that shortcut into my taskbar. But when i open it, it creates a new "element" in the taskbar like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH85m.png). When i create the shortcut from chrome itself (settings -> tools -> create shortcut) and add it to the taskbar, it opens in the same "element", but it is not portable to a different computer, which is something i need. Is there any way to get the "best of both worlds"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Chrome no longer allows me to create shortcuts to open tabs as windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1376060/google-chrome-no-longer-allows-me-to-create-shortcuts-to-open-tabs-as-windows)

Comment: Unfortunately not, it creates a shortcut with the following parameter: `--app-id=adnlfjpnmidfimlkaohpidplnoimahfh`, which works well, but when i reinstall windows, i have to create a new shortcut again

Comment: To transfer the app, you could sign in to Chrome and synchronise everything to your account.Otherwise, you could just copy the profile folder.

Comment: @harrymc i am synchronizing chrome, yet i still have to manually press "install on this computer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found somewhat of a solution: When you create the shortcut using chrome, it doesn't automatically sync. After reinstalling chrome, you hav to go to `chrome://apps` and right click on the app and click "install on this computer"